# Using Stokes' theorem around a circular loop

Tags: integration, vectors, surfaces, stokes-theorem

[image]

I know that I have to use:

$$\oint F\cdot dr = \iint \operatorname{curl}(F)\cdot n \;dS,$$

with $\operatorname{curl}(F)= -x j -yk$ and $n\;dS = dA\; k$

But the dot product of the curl and $dS$ leaves me with
$$\iint -y \; dA$$
but I am unsure how to proceed from here. Do I need to change coordinate systems as I am dealing with a cicle? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're integrating an odd function over a region symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis.  The integral is $0$.

Comment: It has to have a non zero answer apparently

Comment: I'm getting an answer of $-\pi a^2$. This is, of course, assuming the circular loop $x^2+y^2=a^2$ is oriented counterclockwise.

Comment: That would make sense, because it is a circle! Would you please be able to tell me where to go from my working/how you got that?

Comment: Also, what is the surface $S$ you're using in the surface integral $\int _S \text{curl}(F)\cdot \vec{n}dS$ whose boundary is the circle loop $x^2+y^2=a^2$?

Comment: I have included a picture of the full question in an edit

Comment: There are *many* surfaces $S$ such that $\partial{S}$ is the the circular loop $x^2+y^2=a^2$. The parabloid $\{z=a^2-x^2-y^2,z\geq 0\}$, the cone $\{z=a-\sqrt{x^2+y^2},z\geq 0\}$ and the disc $\{x^2+y^2\leq a^2,z=0\}$ are all surfaces whose boundary is $x^2+y^2=a^2$ that you can use in the surface integral $\int_{S}\text{curl}(F)\cdot \vec{n}dS$

Comment: Ah, I think you've computed the curl incorrectly.  This make the integrand $-1$, not $-y$.

Comment: I'm writing you an explanation for this. Bare with me, I type Latex a bit slowly :-/

Comment: Thanks very mcuh Matthew. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply Stoke's Theorem to evaluate $\int_CF\cdot d\vec{r}$ where $C$ is the circular loop $x^2+y^2=a^2$ you need to first establish a surface $S$ whose boundary is $C$ and is equipped with a normal vector $\vec{n}$ that induces the original orientation prescribed to $C$. Let's take $S$ to be the circular disc $$\{x^2+y^2\leq a^2,z=0\}$$ which we'll parameterize by $$\vec{r}(u,v)=(u\cos(v),u\sin(v),0)$$ on the domain $0\leq u\leq a$ and $0\leq v\leq 2\pi$. Clearly the vector $\vec{n}=\big<0,0,1\big>$ is perpendiular to $S$ and induces a counterclockwise orientation on its boundary $C$. (I'm assuming you're prescribing a counterclockwise orientation to $C$.) A little bit of calculation also reveals that $$\text{curl}(F)=\big<0,-1,-1\big>$$ $$\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v=\big<0,0,u\big>$$ $$dS=||\vec{r}_u \times \vec{r}_v||dudv=ududv$$ So with Stoke's Theorem, $$\int_C F \cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{S}\big[\text{curl}(F)\cdot \vec{n}\big]dS=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a -ududv=-\pi a^2$$